# Creating distribution certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two questions for you.
First one is that my distribution certificate is going to expire next month. So I created a new distribution certificate today without revoking the older one. I did it without any problem. But I notice that the new certificate is going to expire on 9th oct 2015 and not 9th oct 2013.  According to my knowledge apple distribution certificates valid for one year. Is this possible.

My second question is I need to create a provisioning profile with this new certificate. And I need the bundle identifier as same as the I used with previous certificate. Can I Create provisioning profile using the same App ID I have used to create previous provisioning profile?